# Should I convert char[] to stream?

Tags: .net, wcf, stream, arrays

I am writing a wcfservice for users to download some files in chunks. Files can be in any encoding. So I used a utility class to detect the encoding, then read the stream from appropriate offset, but `StreamReader.Read(,,)` method reads the file into a `char[]`. So I need couple of suggestions over this situation.
btw max chunk size is 4mb.

1) should I convert the output `char[]` to a `Stream` ? or will it be ok to just have `char[]` sent over the wcf?

2) If I need to convert from `char[]` to `Stream`, how can I do that? (I tried to copy the `char[]` to `byte[]` but didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `MemoryStream.Write` method. For example, the following code will write the contents of a byte[] array into a memory stream:

```
byte[] myByteArray = new byte[10];
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
stream.Write(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.Length);
```

Alternatively, you could create a new, non-resizable MemoryStream object based on the byte array:

```
byte[] myByteArray = new byte[10];
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(myByteArray);
```

Comment: that's not what I'm looking for unfortunately :/ I don't have a `byte []` in my hand, what I got is a `char[]`, and I cannot convert it to `byte[]`. Thanks for the effort though.